# How to manipulate data from a given json input file and save it to required format

Tags: python, json

I have a file `input.txt`, which is actually a list of comma separated 
strings embedded within a JSON structure, where the data within the lines 
are separated by pipes (`|`).

Notice how the `last operation` column has been split in the desired output to LastOperation and OperationTime.

In this case, use two spaces as the field separator/delimiter.?

Input json file is:

```
'{
    "info": {
        "status": "succ",
        "type": "command"
    },
    "data": {
        "list": [
            "CommQ data set name: test.ttq1.tt2.tt3",
            "               size: 19169280 bytes",
            "               used: 537320 bytes",
            "Destination name|status|     last operation     | sent |queued|address",
            "testifLAPPXDgx01    |active|Send OK  14.02.22 07 SEP|    26|     0|testifLAPPXDgx01..test.server ",
            "testifLAPPXDgx02    |active|Send OK  14.02.22 07 SEP|    12|     0|testifLAPPXDgx02..test.server ",
            "testifLAPPXDgx30    |active|Send OK  14.01.49 07 SEP|     7|     0|testifLAPPXDgx30..test.server ",
            "testifLAPPXDgx40    |active|Send OK  14.01.49 07 SEP|     7|     0|testifLAPPXDgx40..test.server ",

            "1105 senders, 0 quiesced"
        ]
    }
}'
```

Output required:

```
[
    {
        "Destination": "testifLAPPXDgx01",
        "Status": "active",
        "LastOperation": "SEND OK",
        "OperationTime": "14.01.49 07 SEP",
        "Sent": 7,
        "Queued": 0,
        "Address": "testifLAPPXDgx01..test.server"
    },
    {
       "Destination": "testifLAPPXDgx02",
        "Status": "active",
        "LastOperation": "SEND OK",
        "OperationTime": "14.02.22 07 SEP",
        "Sent": 26,
        "Queued": 0,
        "Address": "testifLAPPXDgx02..test.server"
    }
]
```

Comment: Actually, your question has little to do with JSON : you are looking for a way to parse the content of `your_json.data.list`. Just split each line on `|` and then (provided you get the right number of pieces), split your 3rd column on double spaces.

Comment: I am not able to do it, troubling in applying loops. If you could provide me the resolution i would be thankful to you as it's critical to me as a assignment task. please provide me the code .

Comment: Show what you have tried so far, explain how it does not work as expected, and you'll be more likely to get help.